# Content script in Firefox extension (SDK) adds up event listeners

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My Firefox extension is providing a JavaScript function that a website can use to access addon functionality. The website calls this function and provides two callbacks.

**Website code:**

```
function onButtonClick() {
  var callbackSuccess = function() { alert("Yeah!"); };
  var callbackError = function() { alert("Oh no!"); };
  if (window.magicAddon) { // Check if my addon is installed
    magicAddon.doStuff(callbackSuccess, callbackError);
  }
}
```

**Content Script:**

```
unsafeWindow.magicAddon = {
  doStuff: function(callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
    // Bind the two callbacks to events. The addon will fire one of them
    self.port.on("doStuffSuccess", callbackSuccess);
    self.port.on("doStuffError", callbackError);

    // Fire the event that lets the addon do stuff
    self.port.emit("doStuff");
  }
};
```

That works great on the first call, but the next time the website calls doStuff(), new listeners add up and alert() is executed twice. Next time three alerts, and so on.

**Any idea how to elegantly avoid that listeners add up? Can I clear an event type completely?**

What not worked so far:

- Using `self.port.once(..)` instead, because I have two callback events: Only the one that fires back is cleared, the other one stays and adds up with the next.
- Before registering new listeners remove the old ones with `self.port.removeListener`, because I don't have the old callback reference.

*Problem seems similar to [How to remove an event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284539/how-to-remove-an-event-listener), only that he uses one callback listener and therefore can use `self.port.once(..)`.*

Comment: Yes, `unsafeWindow` is unsafe and I've read http://bit.ly/rJbtA2, but `document.body.appendChild(script)` doesn't seem much better to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.port.once` and then manually remove the other  callback:

```
doStuff: function(callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
  // Bind the two callbacks to events. The addon will fire one of them
  self.port.once("doStuffSuccess", function() {
    callbackSuccess();
    self.port.removeListener(callbackError);
  });
  self.port.once("doStuffError", function() {
    callbackError();
    self.port.removeListener(callbackSuccess);
  });

  // Fire the event that lets the addon do stuff
  self.port.emit("doStuff");
}
```

You're in a content script, so you can't clear an event type completely, you're able to do so only in main add-on code, and using low level API.

However, I would suggest to avoid `unsafeWindow` to provide this kind of functionality, because, well, it's unsafe. If you maintain your API async, you could use the `postMessage` pipeline between content script and pages, to do the same; and provides a separate javascript file that people can include in their website where you expose an abstraction of postMessages calls (e.g. `magicAddon.doStuff()`). If you want, you could also automatically inject that script from your add-on, in the websites.

Handling this mechanism is definitely a bit more complex, but you can avoid the usage of `unsafeWindow`.

You can find more about content script communication [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html).

Hope it helps!

**Update**: To answer at your comment, you need a variable to trace the `doStuff` call activity:

```
doStuff: function() {
  var executing = false;

  return function(callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
      if (executing)
        return;

      executing = true;

      // Bind the two callbacks to events. The addon will fire one of them
      self.port.once("doStuffSuccess", function() {
        executing = false;
        callbackSuccess();
        self.port.removeListener(callbackError);
      });
      self.port.once("doStuffError", function() {
        executing = false;

        callbackError();
        self.port.removeListener(callbackSuccess);
      });

      // Fire the event that lets the addon do stuff
      self.port.emit("doStuff");
  }
}()
```

Note the `()` at the end. Basically in this way the function set at the end to `doStuff`, is the result of the function we initially assigned.
In that way we create a closure for the `doStuff` method, where a `executing` variable is living, and keep trace if there is already a `doStuff` execution or not, in order to discard any other `doStuff` call, until is done.

*Note: even if in this case is not necessary for javascript, could be a good convention wrap that function in parenthesis, to identify that this function is 'self executing': `doStuff: (function() {...}())*

You could also use property of object of `magicAddon` for this job, but in that case it will be exposed.

Comment: Thank you, that is an excellent idea. However, one follow-up question: The doStuff has user interaction and can easily take up to an hour, or longer if the user goes to lunch in-between. When the website calls the function twice, without waiting for the callback, *both* listeners get *both* callbacks, ending up in 4 callbacks being fired. Any idea on that, too?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the possibility that the website might call `magicAddon.doStuff()` again before receiving the response on the first call. So there might be more than one call executing at any point in time - and you should make sure to call the right listeners. Also, you need to remove both listeners if either callback fires - otherwise you will leak memory. Here is how this could work:

```js
doStuff: function(callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
  // Generate a random call ID
  var callID = Math.random();

  // Bind the two callbacks to events. Make sure to only act on events with the
  // right call ID.
  function onSuccess(id) {
    if (id == callID) {
      callbackSuccess();
      removeListeners();
    }
  }
  function onError(id) {
    if (id == callID) {
      callbackError();
      removeListeners();
    }
  }
  function removeListeners() {
    self.port.removeListener("doStuffSuccess", onSuccess);
    self.port.removeListener("doStuffError", onError);
  };
  self.port.on("doStuffSuccess", onSuccess);
  self.port.on("doStuffError", onError);

  // Fire the event that lets the addon do stuff
  self.port.emit("doStuff", callID);
}
```

This uses a random call IDs to identify calls - the code handling `doStuff` event gets a call ID as parameter and needs to send it back in the `doStuffSuccess` or `doStuffError` events to make sure that the correct callbacks are called.

Comment: Like your idea too, thank you. Why are you using `self.port.removeListener(type, callback)` and others use `self.port.removeListener(callback)`? Are both correct?

Comment: @Doug: No, the `type` parameter isn't optional, see [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/modules/sdk/event/target.html#removeListener%28type%2C%20listener%29). This seems to be simply a mistake in the code ZER0 provided.